# Why is T&& instantiated as int&?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, forwarding, rvalue-reference

Can anyone please explain why this compiles and why does `t` end up with type `int&`?

```
#include <utility>

void f(int& r)
{
    ++r;
}

template <typename Fun, typename T>
void g(Fun fun, T&& t) 
{ 
    fun(std::forward<T>(t)); 
}

int main()
{
    int i = 0;

    g(f, i);
}
```

I see this on GCC 4.5.0 20100604 and GDB 7.2-60.2

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Because of perfect forwarding, when the argument to `P&&` is an lvalue, then `P` will be deduced to the argument's type plus having a `&` attached. So you get `int & &&` with `P` being `int&`. If the argument is an rvalue then `P` will be deduced to only the argument's type, so you *would* get an `int&&` argument with `P` being `int` if you would pass, for example `0` directly.

`int& &&` will collapse to `int&` (this is a semantic view - syntactically `int& &&` is illegal. But saying `U &&` when `U` is a template parameter or a typedef refering to a type `int&`, then `U&&` is still the type `int&` - i.e the two references "collapse" to one lvalue reference). That's why `t` has type `int&`.

Comment: Oh crap, this complicates using r-value references a ton. So I need to write templated code so it will work for both r-value and l-value references? :-/

Comment: @Let: Well, you are forwarding correctly, so what's the problem?

Comment: @Fred The problem is that this code won't work for r-value references (and temporaries), even though the interface provides an r-value reference.

Comment: @Let: It does not work because `f` only accepts lvalues. If you want to limit `g` to accepting lvalues only, see my own answer below.

Comment: @Fred Your post seems to solve this, but I have been talking about writing correct code for both r-value and l-value references.

Comment: @Let: You really want `f` to always mutate `t`, even if `t` is bound to an rvalue? Then simply change `f(forward<P>(t))` to `f(t)`. This works because `t` is a name and hence an lvalue. Yes, named rvalue references are lvalues. Confusing at first, I know :) But maybe you should explain in more detail what you really want to *achieve*. "This code won't work" and "writing correct code" does not tell me anything about your actual *goal*.

Comment: @Fred Uh, why does that work? `g(f,10);` would call `f(10);` but that shouldn't work.

Comment: @Fred I'm just heavily confused about the correct way of writing template functions/methods taking r-value references.

Comment: @Let: No, `g(f, 10)` does *not* call `f(10)`, that would be impossible since `int&` does not bind to rvalues such as `10`. Since `10` is an rvalue, `T&&` is deduced to be `int&&`, and hence `t` is bound to a *temporary object* that is initialized to 10. `t` itself, like all other names, is an lvalue, and as such it can be bound to `int& r`. The modification `++r` can be observed in `g`, simply print `t` to the console and you will see it. **A name is always an lvalue**, even if is the name of an rvalue reference. Does that clear things up?

Comment: @Let: I'm still not clear on one point: Do you want to write a function template that a) accepts **only rvalues** (then see my solution with `enable_if`) or b) accepts **both lvalues and rvalues** (then your `forward` should do the trick)? ... You seem to think that `T&&` somehow means "rvalue reference"? That is not the case due to reference collapsing rules (see Johannes' answer).

Answer (score 3):

If for some reason you really want to bind to lvalues or rvalues specifically, use metaprogramming:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_lvalue_reference<T&&>::value, void>::type
fun(T&& x)
{
    std::cout << "lvalue argument\n";
}

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_rvalue_reference<T&&>::value, void>::type
fun(T&& x)
{
    std::cout << "rvalue argument\n";
}

int main()
{
    int i = 42;
    fun(i);
    fun(42);
}
```